# How to create a code field in django form and save it as a json to the db

Tags: python, django

I am having a usecase where I want to have a code snippet field in django and use that code field value and save it as a json in the DB.

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    rule_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    rule_code = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

the rule_code field should be able to accept code and when reading I should be able to parse as json.

eg:

```
rule_code = a+b
```

while parsing it should be as json.
eg:

```
{"data":{"lval":"a", "rval": "b", "log":"+"}}
```

any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's called a JSONField, and it's part of django's core framework:

```
my_json = models.JSONField(encoder=None, decoder=None, **options)
```

[Django Documentation here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield)